# Flutter stateless and stateful widget question

Tags: flutter, stateless, stateful

I just wanna ask few questions

1. Should i wrap my normal widget with stateless or stateful when using?
2. What is the different of using it as is?

I just wanna build re usable widget and wondering if i should wrap it before re using!
Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StatelessWidget` if your widget will not change value. For example: If you want to display a `Container` with color red and it is not going to change colour.

Use `StatefulWidget` if your widget will change value. For example: If you want to display a number 10, and this number will be increased to 11 or decreased to 9 by pressing a button.